# Cannot get BOOST_FOREACH to work with my custom class

Tags: c++, boost, iterator, boost-foreach

I implemented a trivial class `MyClass` that has an array allocated with `new` inside it (I know that I could use a STL container, but I'm trying to understand how they work). I also created an iterator subclass, able to iterate on all the elements of a `MyClass` object:

```
class MyIterator : public iterator<forward_iterator_tag,int>
{
private:
    int* data= nullptr;
    int length;
    int pointer=0;
    int nullvalue=0;
public:
    MyIterator(int* data, int length, bool end= false)
    {
        this->data= data;
        this->length= length;
        if(end)
            pointer=-1;
    }
    ~MyIterator()
    {
        delete[] data;
    }
    MyIterator& operator++()
    {
        if(pointer!= length-1)
        {
            pointer++;
        }
        else
        {
            pointer= -1;
        }
        return *this;
    }
    bool operator==(const MyIterator& other)
    {
        return pointer==other.pointer;
    }
    bool operator!=(const MyIterator& other)
    {
        return pointer!= other.pointer;
    }
    int& operator* ()
    {
        if(pointer==-1)
            return nullvalue;
        else
            return data[pointer];
    }
};

class MyClass
{
private:
    int* data= nullptr;
    int length= 100;
public:
    MyClass()
    {
        data= new int[length];
        for(int i=0; i<length;i++)
            data[i]=i+1;
    }
    iterator<forward_iterator_tag,int> begin()
    {
        return MyIterator(data,length);
    }
    iterator<forward_iterator_tag,int> end()
    {
        return MyIterator(data,length,true);
    }
};
```

While the iterator works if I use it this way:

```
for(MyIterator i= MyClass_instance.begin(); i!=MyClass_instance.end();i++) {...}
```

It doesn't work if I try to use it with BOOST_FOREACH:

```
BOOST_FOREACH(int i, MyClass_instance) {...}
```

These are the errors that I get:

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- You're slicing your iterator by returning them as `std::iterator<>` ***by value***. You cannot do that.

  Returning by reference would avoid the slicing problem **but** introduces a worse problem: it returns a reference to a temporary¹.

  Hence, fix it by returning your *actual* iterator type by value.
- Your type was missing a const iterator.
- All the iterator members weren't const-correct.
- Also, according to the page **[Extensibility](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_57_0/doc/html/foreach/extensibility.html)** it looks like you need to add

  ```
  namespace boost {
      template<> struct range_mutable_iterator<MyClass> {
          typedef MyClass::MyIterator type;
      };

      template<> struct range_const_iterator<MyClass> {
          typedef MyClass::MyConstIterator type;
      };
  }
  ```
- There is **serious** trouble with the Rule-Of-Three implementation for your iterator type ([What is The Rule of Three?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4172722/what-is-the-rule-of-three)).

  You're deleting the container's data every time an iterator goes out of existence. And `MyClass` itself never frees the data...

Fixing most (?) of the above:

**<kbd>[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/5aded9c74b968671)</kbd>**

```
#include <iterator>
#include <boost/foreach.hpp>

class MyClass
{
private:
    int* data  = nullptr;
    int length = 100;

public:
    class MyIterator : public std::iterator<std::forward_iterator_tag, int>
    {
        public:
            MyIterator(int* data, int length, bool end = false)
            {
                this->data= data;
                this->length= length;
                if(end)
                    pointer=-1;
            }
            MyIterator& operator++()
            {
                if(pointer!= length-1) {
                    pointer++;
                }
                else {
                    pointer= -1;
                }
                return *this;
            }

            bool operator==(const MyIterator& other) const { return pointer==other.pointer; }
            bool operator!=(const MyIterator& other) const { return pointer!= other.pointer; }
            int& operator*() const
            {
                if(pointer==-1)
                    return nullvalue;
                else
                    return data[pointer];
            }
        private:
            value_type* data     = nullptr;
            int length;
            int pointer          = 0;
            mutable value_type nullvalue = 0;
    };

    class MyConstIterator : public std::iterator<std::forward_iterator_tag, const int>
    {
        public:
            MyConstIterator(int const* data, int length, bool end = false)
            {
                this->data= data;
                this->length= length;
                if(end)
                    pointer=-1;
            }
            MyConstIterator& operator++()
            {
                if(pointer!= length-1) {
                    pointer++;
                }
                else {
                    pointer= -1;
                }
                return *this;
            }

            bool operator==(const MyConstIterator& other) const { return pointer==other.pointer; }
            bool operator!=(const MyConstIterator& other) const { return pointer!= other.pointer; }
            int const& operator*() const
            {
                if(pointer==-1)
                    return nullvalue;
                else
                    return data[pointer];
            }
        private:
            value_type* data     = nullptr;
            int length;
            int pointer          = 0;
            value_type nullvalue = 0;
    };

public:
    typedef MyIterator iterator_type;
    typedef MyConstIterator const_iterator_type;

    MyClass()
    {
        data= new int[length];
        for(int i=0; i<length;i++)
            data[i]=i+1;
    }
    ~MyClass() {
        delete[] data;
    }
    iterator_type begin()             { return MyIterator(data,length);      }
    iterator_type end()               { return MyIterator(data,length,true); }
    const_iterator_type begin() const { return MyConstIterator(data,length);      }
    const_iterator_type end()   const { return MyConstIterator(data,length,true); }
};

namespace boost {
    template<> struct range_mutable_iterator<MyClass> {
        typedef MyClass::MyIterator type;
    };

    template<> struct range_const_iterator<MyClass> {
        typedef MyClass::MyConstIterator type;
    };
}

#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    MyClass c;
    BOOST_FOREACH(int i, c) {
        std::cout << i << "\n";
    }
}
```

---

¹ (unless you store the iterators somewhere else, but that would be a huge anti-pattern for many many reasons)

Comment: working sample **[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/5aded9c74b968671)**

Comment: I get an incomprehensible syntax error: "No matching function for call to 'deref'", in the same line where you call BOOST_FOREACH. The problem is inside a struct named struct __iterator_traits_impl<_Iter, true>, inside the STL's iterator header.

Comment: @RamyAlZuhouri interesting. Did you notice the live sample live works? I'd be tempted to assume you're doing something different. I can't really reason about the code you're not showing.